# How to fix the Angular syntax parser error within a Struts 2 <s:checkbox> tag?

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I have encountered a strange error using AngularJS + Struts 2.

I have a Java object `form` with a `boolean` attribute named `paid`.

When I write:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 form-checkbox">
    <s:checkbox name="xxxxx" ng-model="model" 
        ng-init="model = <s:property value = '%{form.paid}' />" 
        theme="simple" />
</div>
```

I get FireBug complaining about AngularJS syntax parser error which directs me to this page:

[syntax error page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%3C&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=1&p3=%3Cs:property%20value%3D%27true%27%2F%3E&p4=%3Cs:property%20value%3D%27true%27%2F%3E)

suggesting expression error.

And if I write:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 form-checkbox">
    <s:checkbox name="xxxxx" ng-model="model" 
        ng-init="%{form.paid}" 
        theme="simple" />
</div>
```

No error is reported. I guess it is because Struts tags begin with `<`, which is not welcomed in Angular.

But, with this line no error is reported:

```
<select ng-model="estadoId" 
        ng-init="estadoId=<s:property value='%{form.estadoId}'/>"
        name="form.estadoId" id="form.estadoId" 
        value="<s:property value='%{form.estadoId}' />"    >
```

So, AngularJS is complaining about `<>` in Struts 2? Or, I am nor permitted to use `<s:...>` inside another `<s:...>`? If the latter is the case, why is complaning Angular not Struts 2??

Comment: If the post *contains* a syntax error, it doesn't mean it is all about a syntax error. More things are involved in this Q&A, as OGNL in dynamic attributes, s:checkbox behavior and so on

Comment: You cannot nest tags like that.

Comment: Illegal JSP constructs aren't related to Angular.

Comment: @Dave Newton Como on. We cannot view these problems so separately. Aren't we in a forum to find questions that we encounter in real life situations? There are seldom "pure" AngularJS or Struts questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first snippet, you are nesting Struts tags, that is a **syntax error**:

```
<s:checkbox name="xxxxx" 
        ng-model="model" 
         ng-init="model = <s:property value = '%{form.paid}' />" 
           theme="simple" />
```

In the second one, you are doing it right with OGNL, but you **omitted the `model =` part**:

```
<s:checkbox name="xxxxx" 
        ng-model="model" 
         ng-init="%{form.paid}" 
           theme="simple" />
```

The right version is the mix of the two:

```
<s:checkbox name="xxxxx" 
        ng-model="model" 
         ng-init="model = %{form.paid}" 
           theme="simple" />
```

Otherwise you could use a raw HTML tag (as in your `<select>` example, that is a standard HTML tag and not an `<s:select>`, hence no tags nesting is happening):

```
<input type="check" name="xxxxx" 
        ng-model="model" 
         ng-init="model = %{form.paid}" />
```

Note: in that case, you should create an hidden parameter under each checkbox to emulate the `<s:checkbox>` tag behavior and make the [Checkbox Interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/docs/checkbox-interceptor.html) happy.

Comment: @FaithReaper is there any problem with accepting the answer ? I've seen you've never accepted an answer, not even the one posted by yourself :| To accept an answer, simply click the white V in the top left corner of the answer, turning it to green... you should also consider going back to your other questions and accepting every answer that solved your problem

Comment: Yes thanks for telling me this. I have accepted your answer.